# How to parse a string in a mortgage calculator to return a double. JAVA

Tags: java, string, double

````
```
Scanner scanner3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String typePrincipal = "";
        while (typePrincipal < 1000 || typePrincipal > 10000000) {
            System.out.print("Principal ($1K - $10M): ");
            typePrincipal = scanner3.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter a value between 1,000 and 10,000,000");
            if (typePrincipal >= 1000 && typePrincipal <= 10000000) {
                continue;
            }
        }

        Scanner scanner4 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String typeInterest = "";
        while (typeInterest > 30 || typeInterest <= 0) {
            System.out.print("Annual Interest Rate: ");
            typeInterest = scanner4.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter a value between 0 and 40");
            if (typeInterest <= 30 && typeInterest >0) {
                continue;
            }
        }

        Scanner scanner5 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String typePeriod = "";
        while (typePeriod > 40 || typePeriod <= 0) {
            System.out.print("Period (Years): ");
            typePeriod = scanner5.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter a value between 0 and 40");
            if (typePeriod <= 40 && typePeriod > 0) {
                break;
            }
        }

        double mortgageResult = typePrincipal*(((typeInterest/100/12)*(Math.pow((1 + (typeInterest/100/12)), (typePeriod * 12))))/(Math.pow((1 + (typeInterest/100/12)), (typePeriod * 12)) - 1));

        NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        String mortgageCurrency = currency.format(mortgageResult);

        System.out.println("Monthly Mortgage: " + mortgageCurrency);
```
````

I started learning Java a day ago and do not understand how to use the Double.parseDouble on the string that I set to null. Is there a way where I could keep the double and use a null value too?

Answer (score 0):

`Double.parseDouble()` will throw an exception if you pass `null` as a parameter. You have to check the input string for `null` first.

If you want to have `null` `Double` object you can do as follows:

```
final String s = null;
final Double d = s != null ? Double.parseDouble(s) : null;
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It says, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Post the code you wrote (only the part where you deal with the String and the Double)